# JavaScript compare two json files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, comparison

I have 2 json files with data, one shows an article with data parameters and the other one shows a list of categories with it's own data parameters.

The article json file has an attribute ID which is the ID of one of the categories in the Category json file.

When I load the page, I need to be able to tell if the article ID is the same is a Category ID. If so, I want the data of the Category to populate some data in the page.

Right now all i've done is to create two ajax requests separately for each json file but I don't know how to make the comparison process...

Comment: Can you include what code you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can just turn the JSON result into a JavaScript Object via JSON.parse.
Then iterate over the categories and find the one you are looking for.

Simplified Example:

```
<div id="output"></div>

(function() {
  var JSON_Categories = '[{ "id" : "1", "text" : "Category A"}, { "id" : 2, "text" : "Category B"}]';
  var JSON_Article = '{"id" : "1", "text" : "Article Text"}';

  var categories = JSON.parse(JSON_Categories);
  var article = JSON.parse(JSON_Article);

  var outputElement = document.getElementById('output');

  categories.forEach(function (category) {
      if (category.id === article.id) {
        outputElement.textContent = category.text;
        outputElement.textContent += ': ' + article.text;
      }
  });

})();
```

http://codepen.io/jjd/pen/WrQNwJ?editors=101